# Ubuntu 18.04 with Debian(?) destop

Tags: 18.04, gnome, nautilus, desktop-environments

I recently compiled `ffmpeg` from source on Ubuntu 18.04 because the version in the repository didn't work. In the process some libraries were overwritten with different versions and some packages got deleted. I didn't write down exactly what it wanted to delete, so I don't remember now. When I rebooted, the proprietary Nvidia-driver was not working and I had to reinstall it. The process ended up leaving me with a funny desktop

[image: Screen after process]

I had never seen this: I always had something like

[image: Screen before process]

I have tried to reinstall `ubuntu-destop`, `nautilus*`, several `gnome-...`, reconfigure things, switch from `lightdm` to `gdm3`and back, but I can't get my desktop back. I don't mind the color and picture, as long as I could have my icons, my tray, the side bar where my programs are and a way to access the other programs that are not locked to the launcher. Now I'm forced to write the program names in the console. This works in principle, but this desktop also has a funny way to maximize the windows, so that I have to keep moving it in order to see everything.

What else can I try?

Comment: @Kulfy The only error I got was that `nautilus-dropbox` and `nautilus-owncloud` couldn't be installed because they needed `dropbox`, which wasn't going to be installed, and another version of `owncloud-client` than the one that was going to be installed. So I just disregarded and didn't install those.

Comment: Reminds me of one of wm's (fvwm comes to mind but likely wrong), so I'd try using it as if you were using openbox, fluxbox etc (ie. does right click on background pull up a menu; I'd also view running processes to look for what it is).  To fix I'd logout and see if you can select "Ubuntu" as your session (desktop) as it may be as easy as that to return to your GNOME desktop,

Comment: @guiverc Unbelievable. It was indeed as simple as that. Who would have imagined that. If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture (especially the icons top right) reminds me of one of window managers  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_X_window_managers). I would try right clicking on the background hoping you get a menu, and logout  (*or just kill the session from terminal if you can't work out how to exit it*).

At the greeter (or login screen) select "Ubuntu" as your session (ie. desktop) to return to the GNOME desktop.  Likewise if you want to explore this session at some future data, you just select whatever it was (I'd expect it to be listed there as a choice); logout if you've had enough & select "Ubuntu" again.

(*my own system has GNOME (Ubuntu), XFCE (Xubuntu), LXQt (Lubuntu), & MATE (Ubuntu-MATE) installed & I select which I want to use today, or which will best suit what I want to do today at my login screen*)

Most of the window managers are really light & fast, though can be lacking some features we get in our heavier desktops (eg. gnome, kde..).

Comment: It was indeed Window Maker. How it got there I don't know. I didn't even know about it's existence.